# Does `ret` also remove all the function's arguments from the stack?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, stack

When `ret` is executed, it pops the (return) address and puts it in the EIP register.
But what about all the function's arguments left on the stack?
Are we just ignoring them and resetting ESP over them? (ESP+8, if there are 2 args)

Comment: You can use either `retn imm16` (eg `retn 8`) to move the stack pointer register by an additional adjustment after popping the return address. Or you can have the caller be responsible for this stack space. Depends on your calling convention.

Comment: @ecm: both standard x86-64 calling conventions are caller-pops, where functions are expected to use just `ret`, not `ret 8`.  And BTW, RSP+=8 would is only one arg, since RSP implies 64-bit code.

Comment: To ecm, yes this proved to be the case

Comment: Peter Cordes, I should write ESP+8 there, you're right.

Comment: If you're talking about 32-bit mode, [edit] your question not to use 64-bit registers like RIP and RSP.  (And to be specific about what context you're talking about, if you have a certain calling convention in mind.)

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is ambiguous even if you declare x86 as the target, because "x86" supports multiple call conventions that differ in this particular aspect.

In [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) you could easily see a bunch of calling conventions in x86-32 world. Well, the most currently used now is "*cdecl*" one which defines that a callee doesn't clear stack from parameters. But, "*pascal*" convention and others, described in "Callee clean-up" section, do this. This convention type can be used only with functions with fixed parameter set.

With x86-64 (AKA amd64, and simply "x64" in Microsoft world), there are two principal calling conventions (Microsoft and Unix (System V)) which both put parameter cleanup burden to caller.

So, nowadays one could assume in general parameters are cleaned by caller... but still keep in a far corner of mind that things may vary (similarly to that in COM port "byte" is not always 8 bits).

Comment: 32-bit `stdcall` and `fastcall` are widely used (on Windows) callee-pops conventions, including for WinAPI functions I think.  "pascal" is an unusual choice of example.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out.

After returning to the caller function, the next instruction is ESP+8. Which essentially resets the ESP while leaving the arguments sitting there in memory (waiting to be overwritten in the future)

Comment: See my answer: while you may rely on this in >99% real cases, you still may encounter specific situations when this isn't true.